# what's wrong with question: on listening to java http requests

Tags: discussion

I asked a question basically on packet sniffing (or whatever the term might be).

> ** [How to identify http requests made from a closed-source java app?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271342/how-to-identify-http-requests-made-with-a-java-app) **

Instead of asking on StackOverflow, I thought it might be appropriate for here.  Looking at your guidlines [What topics can I ask here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) this could fall under a number of your software related themes.  And I don't think it falls under the [**What questions shoiuld I avoid asking?**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) e.g. it is not a rant in disguise.  Certainly, I have separated out the legal issues involved in that question.

I am not interested in raising a polemic. Right now it has **-2 votes** but it has **1 favorite**, which expresses ambivalence on part of the community.  How can I improve this question so it relates more to this site, or should it be moved someplace else entirely?

Comment: as far as I can tell, some readers find your question [unclear](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489) - currently it has 2 votes on that. As for favorite, ignore it, people use this feature for different purposes, it would probably be more accurate to call it "bookmark"

Comment: I find the question perfectly clear, however I've made an edit to your question anyways to fix grammar in a few spots, and remove unnecessary information that may be confusing other users. Feel free to rollback the edit if you don't like it, and good luck with your question :)